# Excel auto fill repeating the same number

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, auto-form-fill

I'm taking the difference of some figures and having trouble amending the figures to reflect what the formula is doing (screenshot below). The autofill function is repeating the same number for the first formula.

Is there a way to autofill in the usual manner where the numbers are not repeated?

[image]

Comment: Is auto calculation turned on? If not, did you press F9 to update the calculations?

Comment: You're welcome. If that is the suitable answer, please accept it by click the check mark on the left under the vote count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sheet calculations are probably set to manual. You can press <kbd>F9</kbd> to do it manually or turn in automatic calculations.

To turn on automatic do the following:

Click the File tab, click Options, and then click the Formulas category.
Do one of the following:

1. To recalculate all dependent formulas every time you make a
   change to a value, formula, or name, in the Calculation options
   section, under Workbook Calculation, click Automatic. This is the
   default calculation setting.
2. To recalculate all dependent formulas — except data tables — every
   time you make a change to a value, formula, or name, in the
   Calculation options section, under Workbook calculation, click
   Automatic except for data tables.
3. To turn off automatic recalculation and recalculate open
   workbooks only when you explicitly do so (by pressing F9), in the
   Calculation options section, under Workbook Calculation, click
   Manual.

Note: When you click Manual, Excel automatically selects the Recalculate workbook before saving check box. If saving a workbook takes a long time, clearing the Recalculate workbook before saving check box may improve the save time.

[Source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/change-formula-recalculation-iteration-or-precision-HA102749052.aspx?CTT=1)

Answer (score 0):

Is the field formatted as number? If not, then I believe that is what would cause it not to increment it as normal.

Comment: It's formatted as `Number`, still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Clear all filters and disable filter by clicking on it again to help with this issue.
After this try autofilling the numbers. It worked for me, hopefully will work for you as well.

Comment: This old question already had an accepted answer so new response are generally not needed